# autocomplete with checking empty inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Here is a part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date_chargement" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date de chargement minimum :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="dateMinChargement" id="datepicker" onblur="VerifChampVide(this)"/>
  </div>
  <label for="heure_debut_chargement" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Heure de début :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="time" class="form-control text-center" name="heureDebutChargement" onblur="verifChampVide(this)">
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false
    });
});

function surligne(champ, erreur)
{
   if(erreur)
      champ.style.backgroundColor = "#B43045";
   else
      champ.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function verifChampVide(champ)
{
   if(champ.value == '')
   {
      surligne(champ, true);
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      surligne(champ, false);
      return true;
   }
}
```

Datepicker works perfectly, so I don't need help on this. But, my problem is that I have created a function in js which change my inputs backcolor when it is empty. It works on all of my inputs on the form except the input where I put datepicker.

I read a lot on the web and I found the autoUpdateInput option. But it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you recreate the bug on a JSFiddle?

Comment: I tried but datepicker didn't work on JSFiddle... So we can't have a true example..

Comment: @Oriel.F So, how can it work on all the document fields and not on Datepicker field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in this line:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="dateMinChargement" id="datepicker" onblur="VerifChampVide(this)"/>
```

You try to call the function ***VerifChampVide***  but you defined it as ***verifChampVide***.  JS is case sensitive.

For the second: because you have a datepicker you need to use the [hide](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#hide) event instead of onblur.

Pay attention to the ***label for*** values and the ***id*** of the input fields.

For the input type time you will get an empty string or a value. The time value is not empty  if the field will be filled to capacity.

The snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false
  }).on('hide', function(e) {
    verifChampVide(this);
  });
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false
  });
});

function surligne(champ, erreur)
{
  if(erreur)
    champ.style.backgroundColor = "#B43045";
  else
    champ.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function verifChampVide(champ)
{
  if(champ.value == '')
  {
    surligne(champ, true);
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    surligne(champ, false);
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datepicker" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date de chargement minimum :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="dateMinChargement" id="datepicker"/>
    </div>
    <label for="heure_debut_chargement" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Heure de début :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="time" id="heure_debut_chargement" class="form-control text-center" name="heureDebutChargement" onblur="verifChampVide(this)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just saw my mistake : "VerifChampVide" instead of "verifChampVide".... I am a bit sad...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You are right. I have to use the hide event, or when I pick a date, the field background remains red.

Comment: I have another problem. In fact, the function change background color only if i click on a date to hide the calendar. But, if the user just tabulate whithout clicking on the field to open the calendar, the filed is not colored.

Comment: @Kuartz Did you include all the libraries listed in the snippet? I tested it with FF, IE and Chrome last versions using the tab key instead of mouse click and I get no problem. On my computer if I move from one field to datepicker using tab key the calendar panel is opened. But, if it is like this, you can add the onblur event to the datepicker. Let me know.

Comment: It works with "Run code snippet". And I tried with my website, the field remains white. I don't understand. I tried to include all the libraries... Anyway, thank you for your help !

Comment: @Kuartz There must be a conflict. You may have directly or not included other libraries. I may suggest you to see into the console for errors. Anyway, thanks so much